# kafka streaming : java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have issue with deleting the state directory within Kafka streaming application. We are running application on inhouse container platform.

Insight into this issue will be much appreciated.

The log of the exception:

> 2018-09-18 09:26:09.112  INFO 1 --- [5-CleanupThread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory       : stream-thread [ApplicationName-1ae22d38-32d3-451a-b039-372c79b2e6a5-CleanupThread] Deleting obsolete state directory 2_1 for task 2_1 as 601112ms has elapsed (cleanup delay is 600000ms).
>       2018-09-18 09:26:09.116 ERROR 1 --- [5-CleanupThread] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory       : stream-thread [ApplicationName-1ae22d38-32d3-451a-b039-372c79b2e6a5-CleanupThread] Failed to delete the state directory.
>
> java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /tmp/ApplicationName/ApplicationName/2_1
>                   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:740) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
>                   at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:723) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
>                   at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:723) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
>                   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:287) [kafka-streams-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
>                   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:250) [kafka-streams-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
>                   at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams$2.run(KafkaStreams.java:800) [kafka-streams-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]

Comment: What version are you using? Maybe you are hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647 or related bug?

Comment: Hi Matthias, we are using kafka-stream 2.0.0 version. I saw issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647 and i will check if this helps with our case. Thanks

Comment: @BhaveshPatel, I am encountering the exact same problem.  Did you ever solve it?

Comment: I am seeing this problem on Windows as well

Comment: I have the same problem in windows, while the kafka stack is in docker container and the service is outside (Spring based)
Do you find a solution for it?