# Failed to delete empty directory in version 2.3.1

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Seems like the problem described in [kafka streaming : java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476045/kafka-streaming-java-nio-file-directorynotemptyexception) persists in version 2.3.1. We upgarded our application to 2.3.1 and a lot of logs like below are produced. The directory, which the cleanup thread tries to remove is empty and can be removed manually only by root user. The application runs in Docker container, with /tmp/kafka-streams dir mapped to physical /streams directory. 
Please, advice. 
Thanks, Mark

Log from application:

> 2019-11-19 07:56:46,951
>   [StringAggregator-8ff4a4d6-5a4f-4bdf-a452-4b01f93a8956-CleanupThread]
>   ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory -
>   stream-thread
>   [StringAggregator-8ff4a4d6-5a4f-4bdf-a452-4b01f93a8956-CleanupThread]
>   Failed to delete the state directory.
>   java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException:
>   /tmp/kafka-streams/StringAggregator/0_27
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
>           at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:769)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:752)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
>           at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:752)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:301)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:264)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.lambda$start$1(KafkaStreams.java:802)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Do you use NFS for the physical  `/streams` directory? If yes, that is known issue. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647?focusedCommentId=16899894&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16899894

Comment: Yes, we use NFS. So, how do we overcome that issue? Is ti something serious, or jsut bad output in the log?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with state directories on Windows and on NFS and a bug is filed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647).

The effect of this bug is that a Kafka Streams client is not able to delete the state directories it used, neither with its clean-up thread nor with an explicit call to `KafkaStreams#cleanUp()`. Basically, the client creates directories that can only be freed by manually deleting them as you experienced.

The file locks should be released after the attempts to delete the directories. So that the directories can be reused by the Kafka Streams client.

From a correctness point of view, this should not be an issue since you say that the directories are empty.

Disclaimer: I haven't verified this with an NFS drive. You could verify if everything works as expected by

1. Deleting all state directories
2. Starting a Kafka Streams client: All tasks are assigned to this client and state directories are created for each task.
3. Adding a second Kafka Streams client: Tasks are rebalanced between the two clients. After a time interval of `state.cleanup.delay.ms` after the rebalance, the cleanup thread should try to delete the state directories of the tasks that were assigned to the second client. Now you should get the `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException` exception stack trace in your logs.
4. Stopping the second client: The tasks of the second client are reassigned back to the first client. The first client reuses the state directories that the cleanup thread could not delete.
5. Stopping the first client.
6. Restarting the first client: The client should reuse the state directories that the cleanup thread could not delete.

During all this

- verify whether the results of the processing are expected
- look after dying StreamThreads (e.g. by using `KafkaStreams#setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`)
- look after log messages like `Failed to release the state directory lock.` right after `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`.

In conclusion, I would recommend not to use NFS for the state directory but rather use local disk.

Comment: 10x, Bruno. I will try with local disk and update you regarding the results.